# What does 'module' in cmake 'pkg_check_modules' stand for?

Tags: cmake

I am building a certain module in GNU Radio. (Let's call it my-module.)

GNU Radio uses `cmake` to build and intall a my-module.

In the project, I need to use a module that was made by others. This can be `it++` and other gnuradio-modules. And I will be using a gnuradio module. (Let's call it `other-module`.)

To use other modules in my gr-module, I need to use `find_package`, `pkg_check_modules` and `find_library` to tell 'I will be using pre-built modules'
And `pkg_check_modules(PC_ITPP itpp)` can successfully detect it++.
But I am having difficulties in finding `other-module`. As I put `pkg_check_modules(PC_OTHER_MODULE other_module)`, it can't detect the module.

What I am curious is, what does `module` in `pkg_check_modules(<PREFIX> <MODULE>)` stand for and how and where does cmake find a given module?

Of course, I don't think it's a kernel module since I don't see it++ in the list of kernel modules. Then, are they cmake-modules? I don't think so, neither, because`cmake --help-module-list` doesn't show it++.

Is there a special file that contains a list of modules that can be referred by cmake? If then, should `it++`and other library, modules be registered in that file at the build and installation steps in order to be recognized as modules by cmake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pkg_check_modules(<PREFIX> <MODULE>)` invokes pkg-config, queries for `<MODULE>` and returns the result in variables which have names beginning with `<PREFIX>_`. Thus module is the name of the software you / pkg-config are looking for.

If your other_module is not found, try directly with pkg-config, whether pkg-config knows about other_module, use `pkg-config --modversion other_module` to do so.

With `pkg-config --list-all` you get a list of all modules known by pkg-config.

If your 3rd party software is not part of pkg-config and there is no FindOTHER_MODULE.cmake provided by CMake, you can google for it. Maybe someone else wrote exactly that test and you can use it. Or you have to write your own test using find_includs, find_library et al.